# Undergrad students grading other undergrads: ethical, professional, or even legal?

Tags: ethics, undergraduate, teaching-assistant, legal-issues, grading

As an undergraduate, I've been working as a TA in an electronics lab for a while. Recently I have been asked to grade other students' lab reports. I have also done some oral examination, but I guess that's relatively fine, since there you can indeed see if he knows what he's supposed to know.

However, when it comes to grading reports, they may be to some extent copied from other reports, may have data tampered with after the lab so they look correct, and in general are made to look correct through collaboration and some Google copy-paste, it becomes very hard to tell who deserves the grade and who doesn't.

Also, I myself wasn't getting good grades at those reports, and I never could understand what those correcting were expecting from me, so I would be grading on a different basis than they are. In fact, I really can't find much wrong with the reports, so I feel like I'm doing a lousy job (even though any time I express doubt about my judgement I am assured that stuff can't go wrong).

One final detail is that it's a hardware lab, and while I'm not bad at it, I'm headed straight to software, so I probably look at things from a different perspective, not to mention that what's important for me may be quite different.

Considering the above worries, does it seem fair that undergrad students grade the reports of younger undergrads, does it seem professional for those in charge of those groups assign such work to undergrad TAs, and finally, is it even legal for an undergrad to affect another undergraduate's grade by handling grading processes?

Comment: It sounds like you may be less than qualified in more aspects of the TA position than just the grading component.  Presumably the experience has had some benefit anyway, helping you decide on software not hardware, helping you decide whether you want to pursue teaching, etc.

Comment: BTW, when it comes to data tampering or unauthorized collaboration, you should punt to the course professor.  Assign a grade objectively based on accepting the data as real and the content as original, and document your concerns about veracity of data and/or plagiarism to the professor, who can determine whether the ethics violations you are concerned about actually occurred, and apply discipline (which may not be a mere adjustment to the grade on a single assignment) appropriately.  You just decide what the grade is, not who deserves it.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I'm qualified to do the assisting part, as they require that we know what are the expected results of a given exercise, which components are responsible for every part of the result, and that we are comfortable with all the cables and stuff. 

Those are the principles I am trying to apply to the grading process, turns out it is easier than I had first thought, but unless I doubt myself I can't keep myself in check..

The professor considers everything to be ok actually, so I've got my rear covered, I'm asking out of general concern.

Comment: So you're a TA who's worried about doing the best job for your students. Congrats - you're doing it right :-)

Comment: So you've never had a question from a student about how to prepare the report, or whether it is important to mention a particular step in the report?  It sounds as if you're qualified as a *lab resource*, but a TA usually must have other skills as well.

Comment: The question of legality almost certainly depends on the examination regulation of your university. There may be some jurisdictions out there which handle this on a general basis, but then we do not know, which jurisdiction applies.

Comment: @BenVoigt, we get those questions all the time, and we suggest that they can give us as much data as possible without getting off-topic so that we can't misjudge them due to lack of data. Can you explain what other skills you consider necessary? BTW I said lab assistant because I don't do any teaching, I only assist students in the lab, since you're getting into terminology.

Comment: @user3079666: Well, grading or answering questions about preparation of lab reports and grade breakdown are typically required of TAs.  I once had a "lab consultant" position for an introductory computer science course when I was an undergraduate, where I helped students save their work, run the compiler, understand the error messages, and discuss their design.  But I had no role in the grading, I didn't even know the grading structure, which differentiated me from a real TA.  It sounds like you signed up for the first but were given the title and responsibilities of the second.

Comment: (and by "save their work", I mean "in accordance with the file naming and encoding requirements of the Java compiler"... not just "how to use the menu to save a document" that any CS student ought to know beforehand)

Comment: @BenVoigt: in CS, the second definition is just as applicable for students learning how to use Emacs and Vim for the first time :)

Comment: @tonysdg: For first time users of those editors, it'd be a miracle if there were any work to save ;)  But we're getting off topic.

Comment: Somewhat tangential to the question, but if anything, I'd consider having students examine other students *orally* somewhat questionable. When students check written assignments or exams, there is at least the theoretical possibility that a professor who is formally the examiner cross-checks results and submitted exams. In oral exams, on the other hand, even though there is a log, a lot depends on the personal impression gathered by examiners (e.g. how swiftly questions could be answered, whether there seemed to be a lot of stalling, etc.). Moreover, in written exams, the stated problems ...

Comment: ... are pre-defined (and thus, again, can be influenced or at least greenlighted by the official examiner), whereas oral exams are in part guided by the examinee (who can direct the conversation towards certain topics or statements), while the examiner has to make up reasonable questions (which in turn can have a significant impact on the performance of the examinee) on the go. Details of this will, however, depend on the respective regulations and general culture in the university.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, I know exactly what you mean, and I do unfortunately have major concerns as to one of the assistants... Thankfully though, if one is not biased, it is very easy to see if they know what's going on - actually if a student has studied, he doesn't need to be pushed to start talking, so we only need to nudge and probe the other ones and then report back with whether or not they seem to know what they should. But grading can be messed up regardless even when done by professors, so I am not so concerned until that gets fixed

Comment: I could totally see this being both ethical and beneficial for teaching undergraduate Bachelor of Teaching students about grading papers. "Okay, everyone, pass your homework to the person sitting on your left for marking."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As to the question in the title it is certainly ethical, professional, and legal.  More than that, in the US at least, it is extremely common (in my experience at both public and private universities).  However, undergraduate TAs should be handled by faculty somewhat differently since the potential for conflicts of interest which arise from grading students in their peer group is higher.

Carnegie Mellon has some very nice resources available on their website for both undergraduate TAs [here](https://www.cmu.edu/teaching/resources/PublicationsArchives/UGTA_TAs-v2.pdf) and for the faculty supervising them available [here](https://www.cmu.edu/teaching/resources/PublicationsArchives/UGTA_Faculty-v2.pdf).  One of the points in your question about which you seemed particularly concerned was grading other students' assignments.  An interesting point from the document for faculty above is the following instruction for faculty:

> Provide clear, explicit grading guidelines to undergraduates involved in grading and evaluation. Without clear guidance, undergraduate TAs tend to be tougher graders than faculty.

So, I would say if you are in doubt about how to grade a particular assignment, you should not hesitate to ask for more guidance from the faculty member you are grading for.  You should also certainly speak to your faculty supervisor if any conflicts arise.  Another quote from the above documents on this point:

> We expect the undergraduate TA to be neutral in teaching or grading, but we must understand that this is a very difficult ideal for anyone to meet. Following are some tips for averting such challenges:
>
> - You and the student should work together to identify potential conflicts of interest. Before the start of the semester, review the list of students with the undergraduate TA. Faculty cannot simply assume there will be no problems; likewise, undergraduate TAs may not be aware of these difficulties or their potential severity. The undergraduate TAs have interacted with the “potential conflict” students prior to the class, and may continue to do so for many semesters afterward. In our survey of undergraduates involved in teaching, a significant number of the students identified problems of this nature.

You might also find [this article](http://college.usatoday.com/2015/06/30/should-you-be-an-undergraduate-ta/) from earlier in the year in USA today interesting.  It's just a quick overview of the social aspects of being an undergraduate TAing for undergraduates.

Comment: As a point of comparison:  I taught at Williams College (entirely undergraduate) for a few years.  They had a pretty strict policy about TAs being used to grade:  they shouldn't be used in cases where the grading is subjective, the professors should provide detailed answer keys for the students to work from, and the portion of the students' final grade affected by the grading of TAs should not exceed 15%.  Compared to this, Carnegie Mellon's policies seem pretty liberal.

Comment: During my masters', I was a TA for an undergrad course, that included close friends. It helps to have clear policy and objectives. I defined beforehand the values of some common errors ("gramatic, -0.25 each") for instance. Then I reviewed all the works, cataloging the errors into categories. Then I assigned the value of each error and did another pass calculating each grade. That way, when asked, you can say, "you did this -X, this -Y and that -Z". Its fair, consistent and impartial. One of those friends failed the course and still let me crash at his place once a week for a semester. :)

Answer (score 35):

It's a fairly common practice at some universities for older undergraduate TAs to grade younger undergraduates' work. My undergrad institution relied heavily on this - it's perfectly legal and ethical SO LONG AS you, the TA, do not discuss one student's grades/work with another student. More generally, a TA in the United States is bound by [FERPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act) as to what is legal or not.

If you're concerned about not knowing what to mark as wrong, consider asking the professor you are grading for for an answer key or an example solution set. They may be unwilling to give this to you outright, but hopefully they will at least walk through an example with you and point out what they're looking for in a fully correct answer.

Comment: In most cases, if you're grading at all, the university will (in the US) require you to undergo FERPA training. I'm surprised the OP hasn't, because I think that stuff would have been covered and they would have been subject to it (but maybe other universities aren't as zealous with mandatory training sessions as mine haha)

Comment: @guifa: My undergrad institution made sure we knew that sharing grades was a *very* bad idea, but there wasn't anything terribly official.  I think the relative size of the university/department will have a lot to do with that.

Answer (score 6):

> Undergrad students grading other undergrads

I've seen much more: undergrad students grading grad students, grad students grading postgrad students and research scholars! Before my opinion I'll state the basic concept:

*Any of those who are qualified with the course subject are considered eligible to evaluate the answer scripts of the subject.* This includes those who didn't complete the degree *per se*. Undergrad students who have completed the subject are said to have more up-to-date knowledge in the subject enough to grade other students of the same.

As a PhD research scholar myself, I felt the same. However, this even occurs in IITs (Indian Institute of Technology, some of the most prestigious institutions in India). Hence, this is something one has to accept. I'll be happy enough - if the grader who doesn't know the subject doesn't grade my course work - irrespective of their age or degree.

Comment: Why is that worse?  In one of my first year grad classes, we had an undergrad TA.  I'm pretty sure he knew the material well and was responsible.

Comment: @Kimball: replaced worse with more. Besides, I've stated the same in my answer before.

Comment: I graded papers for a graduate course while I was an undergraduate, and one of the classes that I took as a grad student had an undergraduate grader.  I'm not aware of any problems arising in either case.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not a matter of ethics or something more. It’s all about sharing. I think if you have prepared yourself and gained some skills that give you some advantages over the others, you can evaluate a master. There are some graduated people who do not have the correct prerequesites for certain areas and somebody who has a only master degree in title, but from experience can give any advice and many times correct graduated people.

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. I tried to fix the grammar of some of your sentences and make them understandable, but I am not entirely certain that I grasped what you wanted to say, so please check whether everything is still according to your intentions. Also, I failed to understand what you want to say with “you can evaluate a master”.

Answer (score 1):

Allowed and legal? yes. Ethical? Absolutely NOT *in practice* in my opinion. I have junior psych majors grading the papers of junior psych majors whom they will almost certainly be competing with for honors.

I do agree with the information from Carnegie Hall shared by @bamboo. HOWEVER, as the information also states, it is nearly impossible to actually achieve these standards, yet universities use UG TAs anyway.

I should mention I have faculty appointments at two undergraduate institutions. One in Europe and one in the US. Comparatively, grading in the US (where I was educated) is laughably subjective. In the UK, exams go through three rounds of refereeing and there are clear and genuine appeals processes. There is also often calibration exercises before the exam is issued or before grading even starts.

In one class I took as a student returning for a second undergrad degree earlier in my career, undergrads graded papers where a rubric and the grading sheet was provided to all students. This transparency was a great practice, but the undergrad TAs **didn't use them** AT ALL and when one TA was asked why she marked something wrong, and then had it pointed out by the researcher who wrote the article that was being summarized by the student who was marked wrong, that the student was not wrong, the undergrad TA said "oops, well I wouldn't appeal it to the course faculty because here are some other things that could have been better." AND COPIED THE FACULTY MEMBER.

The faculty member showed the same deference to the undergrad TAs as they do graduate teaching fellows and other faculty members. THIS is why it's unethical. In other words, like 99.9999999% of any grading questions or appeals in the US, the initial grade stands because faculty in the US are infallible (yes the same group of people who tout intellectual rigor and a peer review process)

*The idea might not be unethical, but in practice it almost always is.*

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry, but it isn't about sharing like @campussano's [answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/59520/7319) suggests. This is - almost certainly - the result of universities cutting costs by hiring under-experienced teaching staff. While you may be able to effectively check your colleagues' lab assignments, you're probably being used as a pawn against the graduate researchers, to lower their overall employment/upkeep costs. University managements very often try this "juniorization": non-tenured Doctors head courses, Ph.D. candidates teach, and undergrads check homework or even serve as teaching assistants. For shame.

What you - not personally, but collectively - should be doing in my opinion is forming a academic staff union (or overthrowing the comatose leadership of the existing union). At the very least people in your situation should get the same pay as their seniors (if not more), to de-motivate this kind of practice.

Comment: Finances are indeed the fundamental motivation, of course, as usual, rationalized by claims about benefits and equity and whatever...

Comment: That's exactly right einpoklum. That is why my department this year decided to fire our dedicated team of Nobel prize-winning TA's and switch to employing uneducated high school dropouts, and to outsource the grading to a sweatshop in Indonesia. When students complain about the poor quality of TA's, we plan to tell them that the Nobel prize winners were overqualified, and that the high school droupouts will benefit from a valuable training opportunity. But we all know that's bullshit, and will be laughing all the way to the bank to cash our inflated yearly bonuses. (/sarcasm and -1)

Comment: @DanRomik, if you're not seeing the corresponding degradation in your environment, so much the better. And, no, I'd not claim that a 23-year-old is in any way clearly better than a 20-year-old in explaining lower-division mathematics to kids who are trying to do the least possible to fulfill a requirement. On the other hand, I do adamantly declare that the 23-year-old grad TA _should_ feel more responsibility... just as a PhD'd faculty, or tenured, etc., _should_ feel more responsibility: commensurate with the relative seniority and potential competence-by-experience of their situation...

Comment: Why do you assume that the OP is paid less than graduate teaching assistants?

Comment: @paulgarrett as it happens you guessed correctly and I am in fact lucky to be at a well-functioning department and university (though we do employ undergrads as readers grading other undergrads' homework, and like other posters I see nothing wrong with that practice), but that's beside the point; my sarcasm was addressed mainly at the over-the-top, conspiracy-theoretic overtones of einpoklum's answer, so I think I would have reacted the same way even if I were in a less well-functioning department.

Comment: @ff524, actually undergrads here only get a CV reference and probably a letter of recommendation, but graduates are paid 64 euros per month due to low and strictly distributed funding, so they aren't really getting much more than us. Are undergrads paid in other countries? Nationwide there are no funds allocated to undergrad students.

Comment: @ff524: I implied this was very likely, I did not make this assumption. However, I would be willing to wager a can of campus vendin machine soda that this is the case, because it's quite prevalent.

Comment: @user3079666: In most (?) countries, graduate students (and I don't mean professionals who do some research on the side, I mean full-timers mostly) get paid. Sometimes they get paid as full-time employees; sometimes they get paid "stipends" or "scholarships"; sometimes they get paid salaries for teaching only, or for research only; and sometimes a combination of the above. But it's generally the rule that they're paid non-token amounts for doing teaching work. I stand by everything I said, my friend. I'm still guessing there's some exploitative scheme going on there.

Comment: @DanRomik: My alma mater had 2 nobel winners in the department of medical research. Both of them are now occasionally giving fiery lectures about the decline of Academia, and how their achievements are unlikely to be repeated in decades to come considering the under-funding of their department. In that department, many lab technicians have been let go (or retired without replacement) and grad students need to train their incoming colleagues to the best of their abilities. Again, that's not to say that they _can't_. They manage. But it's wasteful and suboptimal.

Comment: @einpoklum, I knew they got paid for taking up jobs in the campus, I didn't know that they got paid for lab work though. In any case, in the entire country they don't get paid, so this is how it's done here legally. As for exploitation, we are having a really tough time dealing with the labs as we are right now, with an approximately 70% undergrad staff, so it's a necessity, which is also why I don't want to ask to cut down on the hours. Without us, the labs would be in chaos.

Comment: @ff524 That is quite natural in many places. We have tables for full-time salaries of employees according to their qualification. They do also apply to part-time jobs as grading or TA'ing, you just get the appropriate part.Even if the department head wanted to pay his student the same as a doctor, he is not allowed to do so. Boosting the hours on the contract  instead will also get the dean's office angry.

Comment: @user3079666: You're caught in a vicious cycle. You're trying to make do with the resources you have (and by you, I mean your department, or lab complex, or university) instead of pushing for budget increases; and you somehow manage, but this tends to motivate more cuts. And that's doubly the case if your research output suffers from understaffing or relying mostly on undergrads (which may or may not be the case).

Comment: I truly hope that the people willing to extort a budget increase by willfully failing to help out students are really few, and hopefully none among us. We are facing budget cuts due to a tough economic era for the country, but our job is to function and aid as much as possible, in spite of any or all difficulties.

Comment: @user3079666: It's a two-way "game of extortion", unfortunately. I mean, your university doesn't tell the electric company "we've got less budget, so we'll pay you less". They light up the buildings and make do, or tell the government "we can't run the university without paying our electric bill". But when it comes to people, it's a different game. With a strong union, these kinds of actions are not possible without deliberating with the academic staff and reaching agreements acceptable for both sides; the way things stand now, management does what's convenient for it rather than what's best.

Comment: @einpoklum I'll be the first to admit that academia has all kinds of exploitation, senseless cost-cutting and other stupid things, but there's nothing to indicate anything like that is going on here. Your answer is not helpful because it makes the most negative assumptions possible about human nature. More generally, almost all your answers that I've seen fill in any missing information with the most absurdly negative, sensational, attention-grabbing assumptions and language. They are always full of bad, incompetent or "comatose" people trying to undermine the noble efforts of the "hero" OP.

Comment: ..."hero" OP, who is being used as a "pawn". That's not helpful, and that's why your answers get voted down even when they contain some useful ideas. If you want your answers to get more respect, I suggest that you tone down the rhetoric, and start taking a more scientific and reason-based approach to answering questions. Don't make assumptions about things that aren't in the question, or state clearly when you do. Don't inject your personal and political world-views into the answer. I think you will see that some small changes of this sort will do wonders for your reputation and success here.

Comment: I suppose I can agree w.r.t. toning down the rhetoric, but: 1. I expressly conditioned my answer on the assumption, as I believe it's likely to actually hold, and 2. Of course I should inject my personal and political views into the answer. My answers on this site (as opposed to, say, math.stackexchange.com) are very much based on my views and politics, as are many (most?) people's. In my case it's more evident since my views are perhaps less mainstream, or maybe I'm more, shall we say, passionate about them.

Comment: @DanRomik: Also, I don't mind the votes all that much :-)

Answer (score -2):

My post grad psychology paper was graded recently by another post grad.  It became clear to me by this marker's comments that they, in fact, had no idea of the context of the assignment question, had no idea of the peer reviewed literature surrounding the topic, and, worst of all, could not recognize diagnostic-criteria quotes from the DSM-5 in the diagnostic section of the paper.
It was also obvious that this marker had absolutely no idea of HOW to mark a written/research assignment. I was given a mediocre pass across the board, ie: for every aspect of my paper: referencing, content, synthesis of research, and written communication skills.
My paper was given a poor grade and I am now fighting for my life for the second time in 4 months for some justice in the marking process.  This practice is just plain dangerous.  These so called markers hold the future of other students in their hands.  Why are we paying excruciatingly high fees for university courses if our work is not going to be graded by a qualified professional who is getting paid to do the work.
I work in a psychology clinic where two ex-graduate students attend as patients.  Their lives have been destroyed by this practice.  They are anxious, depressed and traumatised. One of them, once a promising student, now crochets blankets and throws as her therapy. She does not leave her home unless accompanied by her mother and only leaves home to come to sessions at the clinic.  This practice of students marking university papers is borderline criminal.
Students pay high fees and pay the salary of the teaching staff.  Thus it is within the students' right to demand a refund, just like any other commodity.